# How to Specifiy Password And Username of a ovpn File In Command

Tags: 17.10, gnome-terminal, openvpn

How Can I Specify Username And Password of a 'ovpn' file or also known as OpenVpn file in Command

Example :

```
sudo openvpn vpnfile.ovpn --password PASSWORD --username USERNAME
```

Answer (score 3):

This does not directly answer your question, but you can specify the username/password in a separate file by following this procedure:

http://help.vanishedvpn.com/support/solutions/articles/17000035030-how-to-save-password-for-automatic-login-openvpn-windows-linux-

Basically, create a file (let's call it `auth.txt`) containing your username and password on 2 separate lines. Edit your .ovpn file and change/add `auth-user-pass` to `auth-user-pass auth.txt`. Be sure to make sure the permissions on the password file are set appropriately!

Comment: I had to put in the full path for my auth.txt, in my case I put it in as "auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/auth.txt"